# c++ cin value returning 0 instead of the input value

Tags: c++

Hi I am extremely new to c++. Working on an assignment where I need to add up all numbers of input then display the numbers next to eachother with the sum.

**example:**
input: 1234, output : 1 2 3 4  10

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myNum;
    int total = 0;
    int digit;

    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> myNum;

    while(myNum >0)
    {
        digit =myNum %10;
        myNum/=10;
        total += digit;

    }
    while(myNum <0) {
        digit =myNum %10;
        myNum /=10;
        total +=digit;
    }

    cout << "The sum of digit is:" << myNum << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The second while loop was to deal with negative numbers, but down on the `cout` when I put `myNum` to print the value I input it just prints `0` in front of the total, any reason the values aren't being carried over or how I could go about getting it to carry over?

Comment: The program logic guarantees that `myNum` is 0 at the end. And so when you ask `cout` to output it, you get `0`. I would just remove that.

Comment: Tip: instead of repeating the digit summing logic for negative and positive numbers, you can use the `abs` function to find the value-without-negative-sign.

Comment: You can use strings and make them `char array` and then parse any char to integer and find the sum of them this is easier from that.

Comment: Why are you printing the value of `myNum` at the end, which will always be 0, instead of the ***TOTAL*** value that you've diligently calculated?

Comment: In with your development environment you will almost always find a debugging tool you can use to control the execution of the program. With a debugger you can step through your program instruction by instruction and inspect the variables to see what effect the instruction had. This can make finding or narrowing down the location of logical errors much easier.

Comment: `myNum` is changed in the while loop. You could output it before the loop or copy it to save the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated the code to meet your original requirement.  input:1234 output 1 2 3 4 10

The original code printed the `myNum` variable after using the /= operator repeatedly. The result will always be zero.

The requirements specify that each digit of the input must be printed as well as the total. In order to save the intermediate results, a vector is introduced.  As each digit is produced it is pushed into the vector.

Once the input is exhausted, the individual digits and the total can be printed.  The vector is traversed in reverse to print the digits in left to right order.

```
using namespace std;

int main(int arg, char*argv[])
{
int myNum;
vector<int> digits;

int total = 0;
int digit;

cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
cin >> myNum;

while(myNum >0)
{
    digit =myNum %10;
    myNum/=10;
    total += digit;
    digits.push_back(digit);

}
while(myNum <0){
    digit =myNum %10;
    myNum /=10;
    total +=digit;
    digits.push_back(digit);
}

for (auto it = digits.rbegin(); it != digits.rend(); ++it)
   cout << *it << " ";
cout << total << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will be useful to explain why the OP's code did not work and why your solution works.

Comment: Alternative: You could immediately print the input back out again as well as summing it, eliminating both the `vector` and the iteration loop at the end.

Comment: I'm certain there are many improvements possible to the OP's algorithm.  The code was meant to allow the OP to compare and consider the defects of the original.  The requirements are vague but there appears to be spaces in output: 1 2 3 4 so just printing the input would not be quite right.

Comment: Hey this was really helpful thank you! In my class we havent used vectors yet or a lot of these syntaxes but this seems to make some decent sense, I was wondering what the digit pushback syntax does? Or should I just hold out till we get to that in class hahaha, either way thank you all !

Comment: @AidanAgee Accepting the answer would be appreciated.  push_back adds an element to a vector,  see details and examples here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @MatthewFisher 1. You do not need two loops: if n < 0 then n =-n. 2. You do not need vectors to print the output exactly as specified.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that more optimal algorithms exists.  The answer was meant to help the OP understand the issue with the solution.  The answer was not meant as an optimal solution.  It would be fun to see the code golf solution.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a container if the sequence of digits is not required strictly in the same order.

You can simply print them as you go...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myNum;
    int total = 0;
    int digit;

    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> myNum;

    cout << "The sum of digits : ";
    while(myNum > 0)
    {
        digit =myNum %10;
        myNum/=10;
        total += digit;
        cout << digit << " ";

    }
    while(myNum < 0) {
        digit =myNum %10;
        myNum /=10;
        total +=digit;
        cout << digit << " ";
    }

    cout << "is : " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```